# Calculate group centroid using R

Tags: r

```
mydat=iris

#split sample

index <- sample(1:nrow(mydat),round(0.70*nrow(mydat)))
train <- mydat[index,]
test <- mydat[-index,]
str(train)
z <- lda(Species ~ .,data = train)
z
```

How can i calculate group centroid, so that output would be

```
IRISTYPE    Function    
          1       2
set -   7,608   ,215
vers    1,825   -,728
virg    5,783   ,513
```

So i need get this function of group centroids.
How to do it?

Comment: It's just `z$means`. See [this CV question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92157/compute-and-graph-the-lda-decision-boundary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it this what you are looking for?

```
install.packages("candisc")
library(candisc) 

iris.mod <- lm(cbind(Petal.Length, Sepal.Length, Petal.Width, Sepal.Width) ~ Species, data=iris)

iris.can <- candisc(iris.mod, term="Species")

iris.can$means
```

if you type iris.can$means it will show those values